# What's the "trick" in log derivative trick?

Tags: logarithms, partial-derivative

The following is often referred to as the "log derivative trick".

$$\frac{\nabla_\theta p(X,\theta)}{p(X, \theta)} = \nabla_\theta \log p(X,\theta)$$

For example [here](http://www.1-4-5.net/~dmm/ml/log_derivative_trick.pdf), [here](https://danieltakeshi.github.io/2017/03/28/going-deeper-into-reinforcement-learning-fundamentals-of-policy-gradients/), and several other places (usually in reference to reinforcement learning)

Is it not just calculus? $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \log f(x) = \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$ 
Is there anything else going on here?

Comment: Not familiar, but your second reference seems to use the term not referring to the simple calculus identity, but rather an application of it in computing the less trivial identity $\nabla_\theta E(f(X))= E(f(X)\nabla_\theta \log p_\theta(X))$

Comment: I can't tell you how many times I've been asked when teaching "how did you know to rewrite the expression that way?" Just cause the identity is obvious doesn't mean it was obvious it could be used to solve this problem. It's one of many cases where "taking a log" in some sense helps.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I see your point and I do agree. If someone asked how do you get from $\nabla_\theta E(f(X))$ to  $E(f(X)\nabla_\theta \log p(X;\theta))$ it makes more sense to "ground it out" to simpler calculus rather than say I used a "trick". A trick sounds more opaque and mysterious IMHO.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a "trick", when you use it to calculate $\nabla_\theta p(X,\theta)$ via the (hopefully, sometimes) easier expression $\log p(X,\theta)$. So the use is to write it as 
$$
\nabla_\theta p(X,\theta)=p(X,\theta)\,\nabla_\theta\log p(X,\theta),
$$
in cases where the right-hand-side is easier than the left-hand-side. Typically, when $p$ has lots of products and exponents.

Comment: I understand it is useful to do. But aren't you just rearranging the derivative of the log of a function?

Comment: Yes. That's the "trick". It looks stupid because you are looking at the given expression. But the idea is that you are given a complicated expression, and then you use the right-hand-side instead of calculating the derivative directly. It is a "trick" in the same sense that integration by substitution or by parts is.

Comment: I see your point. It's semantics, I guess, when I hear "trick" I imagine some fancy derivation so I was worried I was missing something.

Comment: Dear author, my understanding is calculating the derivatives of $P$ w.r.t $\theta$ is not computationally feasible in some cases. So instead, we use $\nabla_\theta p(X,\theta)=p(X,\theta)\,\nabla_\theta\log p(X,\theta)$ because normally complex multiplication of equations are converted into sum of equations and the derivatives are easier to be calculated. Is my understanding right?

Comment: Yes. $ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $

Answer (score 6):

Your are absolutely right, this is "just" calculus. But the real question here is, in what context is this trick used?

If you have an expectation value of the form

$\int d x ~p(x, \theta) f(x)$

with a parametrized probability distribution $p(x, \theta)$. It often happens that you want to calculate the derivative of this expectation value with respect to $\theta$, e.g. to maximize or minimize the expectation value.

The derivative takes the form

$\int d x ~\nabla_{\theta} p(x, \theta) f(x)$.

In practice it can be very difficult to calculate such an integral analytically, so you could estimate it via Monte Carlo sampling. But to do this, you need to bring it to the form:

$\int dx ~p(x) F(x) \approx \frac{1}{n_{MC}} \sum_{x_i} F(x_i)$,

where $x_i$ is sampled from p(x). If we now extend the integral from before by the factor $p(x, \theta)/p(x, \theta)$ and apply the log trick we get.

$\int d x ~p(x, \theta)~\nabla_{\theta} \log (p(x, \theta)) f(x)$

Now with $F(x) = \nabla_{\theta} \log (p(x, \theta)) f(x)$ we obtain exactly the Monte Carlo form from before and we can estimate the integral.